# compile less preserving blank lines

Tags: node.js, less

I have the following string:

```
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/src/styles.less */

.main {
  color: white;
}
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/global.less */

body {
  background-color: black;
}
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/src/module/styles.less */

.module {
  background: blue;
}


/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/some-other-global.less */
body {
  color: red;
}
```

and the following code:

```
var less = require('less');
less.render(str)
  .then(function(output){
    console.log(output.css);
  });
```

which gives me:

```
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/src/styles.less */
.main {
  color: white;
}
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/global.less */
body {
  background-color: black;
}
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/src/module/styles.less */
.module {
  background: blue;
}
/* file: /Users/andrepadez/develop/vigour-io/gaston/test/to-compile/some-other-global.less */
body {
  color: red;
}
```

I need my output.css to preserve the original blank lines. Is there an option i could pass to the render function to do this?

Comment: In short: no, there's not.